# Handling Mobiscroll Date Time picker in UFT

Tags: siebel, mobiscroll

I am working on a siebel application which is using Mobiscroll for date time picker for seting the dates/Times. I am not able to get the past/future dates from this. It looks something like below. Can anyone give some idea how it can be handeled?
http://mobiscroll.com/component/datetime
[mobiscroll link](http://mobiscroll.com/component/datetime)

Comment: The Date & Time picker lets you pick a specific date. Which past & future dates are you looking for?

Comment: I want to scroll the Date TIme Drum, which pops up. How can that be Done